# Is stereoscopic vision via OTG and 2 USB cameras possible?

Tags: usb, camera, usb-on-the-go, multiple-devices

I'm thinking of making a stereoscopic night vision device by using 2 USB cameras connected via OTG (type C) to my Android phone. I've already tested 1 USB camera and some VR App from the Play Store and it was a success.

Will 2 cameras work if connected to the same OTG cable via a USB splitter/hub of some sort? Is there a way (or app) to display one camera over half of the screen and the other camera in the other half? Is it even possible to have 2 cameras powered and displayed at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even possible to have 2 cameras powered and displayed at the same time?

It's possible and supported on Android by a number of APK, but never worked for me.

I just purchased USB camera endoscope and plan to install 2 or 4 of them via USB OTG hub (active or passive).

The problem is, APK searchable via Google Play don't support extra features in trial or free mode. On the other hand, it makes no sense to buy one another APK, over and over again just for a test to learn it failed to work for me.

The only APK which worked for me with my new USB camera endoscope is the one named in the manual, "AN98", but I don't get HD image resolution as claimed by a manufacturer. I get a very, very, very, low resolution to work in video mode 30 FPS.

Other endoscope APK failed to show any video or claim connection problems.

So to answer the question: Yes, you can. Try every APK which is relevant and claiming to support 2 USB OTG cameras via a passive or active hub.

Comment: Regarding the app AN98, did you mean [this "AN98" on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AN98)?

Comment: Yes, AN98 from Play store or direct APK download
from
--www.kkmoom.com/an99.apk
or
--www.kkmoom.com/pc.rar for PC

the issue is my endoscope camera comes with 10m cable and Android rejects it

explained why:

"http://www.yourcablestore.com/USB-Cable-Length-Limitations-And-How-To-Break-Them_ep_42-1.html


"https://superuser.com/questions/64744/maximum-length-of-a-usb-cable/64747#64747